# mac os x 10.10.1, php mcrypt listed but does not work with apache

Tags: php, macos, apache, mcrypt

Ok, I know that there are 2000 threads about this topic, but in the whole day I didn't find something related.
I just want to enable mcrypt, I am using Apache on Mac OS X 10.10.1.

I have Apache/2.4.9 installed, and I have installed php56 and mcrypt through brew: `brew install autoconf php56 mcrypt php56-mcrypt` and all the additional dependencies.
PHP version: `php -v`: PHP 5.6.3 (cli) (built: Nov 25 2014 17:28:36).

Now, the PHP configuration files are the following:

```
php -i | grep \.ini\$
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/php.ini
Additional .ini files parsed => /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/conf.d/ext-mcrypt.ini

cat /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/conf.d/ext-mcrypt.ini
[mcrypt]
extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php56-mcrypt/5.6.3/mcrypt.so"
```

So it's loaded, right?
The ouput should confirm this:

```
php -m | grep mcrypt
mcrypt
php -i | grep mctypt
mcrypt
mcrypt support => enabled 
mcrypt_filter support => enabled
mcrypt.algorithms_dir => no value => no value
mcrypt.modes_dir => no value => no value
```

This should confirm that the PHP installation & configuration part should be OK!

Now, the Apache part. I have modified my /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf file, that now has the following line:

```
LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/opt/php56/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

sadly, `<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>` is not what I want because it does not show the mcrypt section. A Magento website gives me `Fatal error: Call to undefined function mcrypt_module_open() in /Library/WebServer/Documents/wow/lib/Varien/Crypt/Mcrypt.php`.

I am seriously desperate. I am a Linux user, all that I had to do was `sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt`. Now it's the whole day that I fight with this problem on Mac OS X. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: This is nowhere near an answer, but is enough for a comment. Here is what I found: http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/how-to-install-mcrypt-for-php-on-mac-osx-lion-10-7-development-server/ Maybe it will work for 10.10. Same website: http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-mcrypt-php-mac-osx-10-9-mavericks-development-server/ but for 10.9 now. I hope this helps.

Comment: Check the `phpinfo()` and make sure the apache module is using the same config files and extensions. OS X comes with PHP preinstalled, if it's using the system PHP then it won't have your changes. Make sure you restart Apache after any changes to the config files for PHP or Apache (`sudo apachectl restart`)

Comment: yep @JeremiahWinsley the path was different, forgot to mention that I've made a copy of the php.ini file so this SHOULD not be the problem. @ Ismael thanks, the point is that I have already installed the mcrypt stuff so installing again should not change the problem...anyway I'm quite desperate, I will try even this probably :)